# Copy Range of Data and paste in recording sheet without overwrite and follow the next available line

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to VBA but i manage to gather up a code that I actually need.
but the code is recording multiple rows in one row. I need to record range of rows every week and clear master sheet only specified columns.
2nd issue is is not recording to the next available row when I press the macro button 2nd time.please help me to sort this out. here is my Code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub UpdateReport2()

    Dim historyWks As Worksheet
    Dim inputWks As Worksheet
    Dim RngToCopy As Range
    Dim nextRow As Long
    Dim oCol As Long


    Dim myCell As Range



    Set inputWks = Worksheets("Master Sheet")
    Set historyWks = Worksheets("report")

    With historyWks
        nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    End With

    With inputWks
        Set RngToCopy = Range("a2:j56")

        If Application.CountA(RngToCopy) <> RngToCopy.Cells.Count Then
            MsgBox "Please fill in all the cells!"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    With historyWks
        With .Cells(nextRow, "A")
            .Value = Now
            .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        End With
        .Cells(nextRow, "B").Value = Application.UserName
        oCol = 3
        For Each myCell In RngToCopy.Cells
            historyWks.Cells(nextRow, oCol).Value = RngToCopy.Value
            oCol = oCol + 1
        Next myCell
    End With

    'clear input cells that contain constants
    With inputWks
      On Error Resume Next
         With .Range("b2:j56").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
              .ClearContents
              Application.GoTo .Cells(1) ', Scroll:=True
         End With
      On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: One quick note, `Set RngToCopy = Range("a2:j56")` is missing the `.` before `Range()` to link it to `inputWks`. Thus, the `RngToCopy` is always going to be from the `ActiveSheet`, whatever that may be.

Comment: Since you're new to VBA, have you tried to step thru the code using F8 and break points?  Here's a good how-to: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html.

Comment: Also, what's the `Application.GoTo .Cells(1)` supposed to do?

Comment: @BruceWayne He clears that range on the Master sheet, and moves focus to Master sheet range B2.

Comment: I see you tried to add the images to the answer below. You should [edit] them into your question, instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a few errors in your code that I've corrected for you. This code works for me. It takes the 10 columns of data from "Master sheet" and places all of the data on 1 row in "report". On the report page, it places everything on the next available row.
**Issues I found:**

1. You didn't define which worksheet your range was coming from when Setting `RngToCopy`
2. In your `For Loop`, you were trying to get the value of your entire range. What should have gone there was your Variant.Value `myCell.Value`

**Note:** I removed a lot of your `With blocks`, not because they were wrong or anything like that, just a personal preference. I left notes in the codes where errors were corrected.

```
Option Explicit
Sub UpdateReport2()

    Dim historyWks As Worksheet, inputWks As Worksheet
    Dim RngToCopy As Range, myCell
    Dim nextRow As Long, oCol As Long

    Set inputWks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master Sheet")
    Set historyWks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("report")

    nextRow = historyWks.Cells(historyWks.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    Set RngToCopy = inputWks.Range("A2:J56") 'assigned the sheet the range comes from

    If Application.CountA(RngToCopy) <> RngToCopy.Cells.Count Then
        MsgBox "Please fill in all the cells!", Title:="Missing Data"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With historyWks.Cells(nextRow, "A")
        .Value = Now
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    End With

    historyWks.Cells(nextRow, "B").Value = Application.UserName

    '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>THIS IS THE FOR LOOP TO CHANGE<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    oCol = 3
    For Each myCell In RngToCopy.Cells
        historyWks.Cells(nextRow, oCol).Value = myCell.Value 'you want the cell value, not range value
        oCol = oCol + 1
    Next myCell
    '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    'clear input cells that contain constants
    On Error Resume Next
       With inputWks.Range("B2:J56").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            .ClearContents
            Application.GoTo .Cells(1) ', Scroll:=True     
       End With
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

**To Transfer Master Range to One Row on record**

```
oCol = 3
For Each mycell In RngToCopy.Cells
    historyWks.Cells(nextRow, oCol).Value = mycell.Value 'you want the cell value, not range value
    oCol = oCol + 1
Next mycell
```

**To Transfer Master Range to One Column on record**

```
oCol = 3
For Each mycell In RngToCopy.Cells
    historyWks.Cells(nextRow, oCol).Value = mycell.Value 'you want the cell value, not range value
    nextRow = nextRow + 1
Next mycell
```

**To Transfer Master Range to record, Offset by Date and Username**

```
For Each mycell In RngToCopy.Cells
    historyWks.Cells(mycell.Row + nextRow - 2, mycell.Column + 2).Value = mycell.Value 'you want the cell value, not range value
Next mycell
```

**To Transfer Master Range to record, Columns and Rows swapped**

```
For Each mycell In RngToCopy.Cells
    historyWks.Cells(mycell.Column + nextRow - 1, mycell.Row + 1).Value = mycell.Value 'you want the cell value, not range value
Next mycell
```

Comment: Thanksyou very much Tyeler for the prompt response but Its still writing all the code in one row but I would like to have all 56 rows from master sheet to record sheet every day when I press the button follow the previous day recording.

please giude me with full code.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @senthuran I don't really understand your question.. I've updated my answer to list a bunch of different options. Just swap out your `For Loop` for whichever one fits your needs.. Maybe a picture of what you want the end result to be would help.

Comment: Thanks Tyeler, your Transfer Master Range to record, Offset by Date and Username is working perfectly OK for me but when I create another record in master sheet  press the button to record in "record sheet" its overwriting on previous record. I wanted to use the next available blank row to record each time.please see the screen shot thanks again.

Comment: @senthuran Sorry, there is one more change you have to make I forgot to tell you about. On the line where you first define `nextRow`, it should be searching in column C, not A. `nextRow = historyWks.Cells(historyWks.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row`

Comment: @senthuran If your report sheet looks too cluttered, on `nextRow` you can change the `.Offset(2,0)` to put a space between record entries. Should make it easier to navigate, if it works for you. If I've answered your original question, would you mind marking this as the answer? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much Tyler ,it's working perfectly as I expected thank to you.ill make this question as answered now. Thanks again.kindly Senthuran